# Error debugging C code with DLL at Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, dll

I'm using Eclipse C/C++ IDE with MinGW to run and debug my aplications.
When I run it works fine but when I debug my application crash

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void loadDLL() {
        int handle = LoadLibrary("teste.dll");
        printf(handle == 0 ? "\n DLL not loaded." : "\n DLL loaded.");
}

int main() {
    loadDLL();

    printf("\n Press any key to exit.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Running my application:

```
DLL loaded.
Press any key to exit.
```

And when I debug then:    http://s30.postimg.org/bxgrdry5t/error.png

The error occurs when I **Step Over** at **LoadLibrary**.
My DLL was created with Borland C++ IDE and I can't change it.

Comment: I don't want to debug my DLL, I just want to step over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend found the solution of the problem!

I needed o **uncheck** an option at my application launcher.
The option is **Load shared library symbols automatically** at:

*AppLauncher >> Debugger >> Shares Libraries*

[image]